# asp.net retrieving/persisting session object from SQL server

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have an application that is using SQL Server to store sessions. I have a session object in the base page wrapped as a Property that I am using through out the application. The property is retrieving the session as:

```
Dim myObj As Customer = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("CustomerSession"), Customer)
```

1) Is **myObj** is a Reference object or is a local variable?

2) Also, if I get/set properties of myObj as:

```
Dim firstName as String = myObj.FirstName
myObj.FirstName = "test 12313"
```

Does the above Get/Set FirstName makes a call to database? Or it is only Retrieving/Setting the value to local variable until the object is persisted back to the Session which means saving to the SQL Server database like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session("CustomerSession") = myObj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya because  its hard for sql server track changes for each session variable and update it..

Answer (score 0):

my obj is local variable asp.net can keep refrence of memory object,but not a permenent storage,so as my view u have to restore it by your last statement...

Comment: does that mean following two calls won't be persisted to database until we exclusively set the "CustomerSession" object with myObj?

**Dim firstName as String = myObj.FirstName**

**myObj.FirstName = "test 12313"**